# SQL Server: dynamic ORDER BY and if input param is NULL do not ORDER BY?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-order-by

I am trying to modify a stored procedure that I have to include a Input parameter `@OrderBy`.

But I need to test it to say if its NULL then don't include the `ORDER BY` in the `SELECT` SQL

If its NOT null then I want to order by on `@OrderBy`

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See also: stackoverflow.com/questions/149380

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can accomplish this using dynamic SQL

```
Declare @dynamicSQL nvarchar(5000);
Declare @orderBy nvarchar(50);

Set @orderBy = 'column1';

Set @dynamicSQL = 'Select * from Table ';

If (@orderBy IS NOT NULL) BEGIN
  @dynamicSQL = @dynamicSQL + 'Order BY ' + @orderBy;
END

exec @dynamicSQL;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it like you say purely is to use dynamic SQL, but a CASE statement often works just as well:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo f
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @OrderBy IS NULL THEN f.Whatever ELSE '' END
```

Comment: if `f.Whatever` is an int your query will fail with the following error.  `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '' to data type int.`  If your running SQL Server 2008 you will get this error `A constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list, position 1.`

Comment: That's true, but the poster didn't specify anything about his query.  In my query, f.Whatever is a character string.  :)

Comment: .Understood... I just wanted to point out that if dynamically you are choosing a column to order by, then to keep from annoying errors like above; Dynamic SQL is probably safer, and more reliable.